# How to check if NTP server is running on a Linux machine by a python script

Tags: python, process, ntp

I need to get IP address of a machine and check if NTP server is running on that. In addition, if it is not running, just start it.
I checked several posts and non of them worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) for this. It's great! Here's a quick and dirty way:

```
from fabric.api import run

def restart_ntp_if_not_running():
    run('if [[ $(netstat -p tcp -n | grep [your ip].123 | grep ESTABLISHED) ]]; then true; else [your command to restart here]; fi;')
```

The execute this like:

```
fab -H [host name] restart_ntp_if_not_running
```